# Como colocar uma variável de php em uma query do mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Por exemplo:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tabela (data, assunto, destino, elaborado) VALUES('{$data}', '{$assunto}', '{$destino}', '{$elaborado}')";
```

Onde está `tabela`, eu quero colocar uma variável no lugar, pois dependendo do que o usuário escolher, vai usar uma tabela diferente.

Já tentei com aspas, com ponto, com chaves...

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-c%c3%b3digo-sql-no-meu-c%c3%b3digo-php)

Answer (score 5):

No PHP quando você tem uma string envolvida com aspas duplas. O interpretador PHP irá percorrer a mesma e verificar se não tem nenhuma variável para ser substituída.

```
<?php
$tabela = 'Tabela1';
$data = '2018-06-20';
$assunto = 'Assunto';
$destino = 'Destino';
$elaborado = 'Elaborado';

$query = "INSERT INTO $tabela (data, assunto, destino, elaborado) 
VALUES('$data', '$assunto', '$destino', '$elaborado')";

echo $query;
```

O trecho `echo $query;` irá imprimir `INSERT INTO Tabela1 (data, assunto, destino, elaborado) VALUES('2018-06-20', 'Assunto', 'Destino', 'Elaborado')`

Answer (score 4):

A resposta do Thiagosilr está correta, basta colocar os nomes das variáveis dentro da string com aspas duplas. Entretanto, sugiro não utilizar esse método para formar *queries* a serem executadas no seu banco, pois o torna vulnerável  a [ataques de injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL).

Por exemplo, se o usuário tem controle do conteúdo da variável `$assunto` através de um formulário, poderia preenchê-lo como `'1'); DROP DATABASE ...` e tentar destruir seu banco só de pirraça.

Uma forma de executar esse mesmo `INSERT` garantindo que as variáveis de entrada não causem estrago é utilizando `prepared statements`, como demonstrado nas respostas para [esta pergunta do SOE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Assim, se estiver usando MySQLi, você instancia um objeto de *statement* usando o método `prepare()` de seu objeto de conexão, especificando as lacunas para parâmetros de *bind* usando pontos de interrogação, depois passa os parâmetros em ordem no método `bind_param()` do *statement* por fim o executa:

```
//cria o statement
$statement = $dbConnection->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabela (data, assunto, destino, elaborado) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");

//passa as  variáveis para preencher os pontos de interrogação
//o parametro 's' significa que você está passando uma string. É como um printf...
$statement->bind_param('s', $data); 
$statement->bind_param('s', $assunto); 
$statement->bind_param('s', $destino); 
$statement->bind_param('s', $elaborado);

//executa o statement
$stmt->execute();
```

Note que um *prepared statement* só suporta que sejam parametrizados os **valores** de uma query. Assim, a variável de nome da tabela deve ser passada com concatenação de string simples como na resposta do Thiago. Imagino que seja algo pouco provável que tal variável seja um vetor de ataque, uma vez que é algo pouco usual permitir que o usuário de uma aplicação decida sobre qual tabela do sistema pretende consultar.

Answer (score -6):

Uma forma é usar da seguinte forma:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tabela (data, assunto, destino, elaborado) VALUES({$data}, {$assunto}, {$destino}, {$elaborado})";
```

Sem as aspas simples.

Comment: Sem as aspas simples, o MySQL não irá considerar os valores como strings; sem contar que desta forma abre espaço para SQL injection como comentado na resposta do nunks.

Comment: Você fez exatamente o mesmo da pergunta, só que piorou, porque removeu os apóstrofos, logo provavelmente vai ter erro de sintaxe na hora de executar. Tem 2 respostas já na pergunta, mas aparentemente você não se deu ao trabalho de ler elas e saiu presumindo uma "solução", recomendo que leia, estudo e depois tente sugerir algo, porque se não você vai ensinar os seus erros para pessoas que estão aqui para aprender.